# How to ignore caret and tilde while npm install?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, yarnpkg, package.json

I have caret and tilde in my `package.json` and I want to keep it as it is.
How can we install the exact version defined in `package.json`?

with `^1.2.3` if we run `npm install / yarn install` then It will install the latest version `>=1.2.3` and `<2.0.0`
it there any command which will install `1.2.3` without removing caret from the version

Comment: someone make a close request to this question. Can you state the reason in the comments too?

Comment: The behaviour you're describing is what's _supposed_ to happen. If you want specific versions then either `--save-exact` (so there's no caret or tilde) or use a lockfile to represent the resolved dependency tree.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, would there be any option to apply this as well on the dependencies of the dependencies and so on, or the --save-exact only works with the initial dependencies listed on the package.json?

Comment: @byuu `--save-exact` is for _your_ package file, the specificity of your transitive dependencies will depend on what's defined in _their_ package files. But the lockfile describes the whole tree.